# Учет расхода sql

Tags: sql

Имеются таблицы:

"Фрукты"
"Овощи"
"Расходы"

Как отразить в таблице Расходы что было потрачено такое то количество фруктов или овощей в одной записи? Я думаю, в таблице Расходы сделать 3 поля "тип_расходуемого", "код_фрукты" и "код_овощи" - внешние ключи. И каждый раз, одно из полей внешних ключей будет пустым. Мне такое решение не очень нравится.
И если появится еще один вид продукта, для которого нужно еще одну таблицу и соответственно поле в таблице Расходы.

**UPDATE 1**

Помимо таблицы Расходы существует таблица Приходы. В приходах учитывается то, сколько было получено таких-то продуктов. Приходит продуктов как правило много. По прибытию продукты должны быть сгруппированы по типу. Группа (или партия) нужна для того чтобы учесть срок годности новых продуктов. То есть, появляется таблица Группы, у которой есть поле "срок истечения годности продуктов" относящихся к этой группе. 
Таким образом в таблице продукты могут быть продублированы записи продукта.

Итого таблицы:

- Типы (id, name)
- Продукты (id, product_type_id, groups_id, name, count)
- Расходы (id, products_id, count, date)
- Приходы (id, products_id, count, date)
- Группы (id, products_id, exp_date)

Меня смущает то, что каждый раз при создании записи о продукте, нужно вводить его наименование, а не выбирать из списка уже существующих. 
Например, была бы таблица Фрукты (id, name), пользователь бы выбирал из нее вид фрукта и добавлял продукт.

Comment: по поводу update 1, что в `Продукты` делает `count`? это остаток количества? какова связь между `Продукты` и `партии`? один к одному? один ко многим? в первом случае их следует объединить, во втором, вероятно, следует перенести `count` в `Группы`, а в `приходах` и `раcходах` ссылаться на `группы`, а не на продукты.

Comment: Количество имеющегося продукта этого вида. Один к одному.

Comment: в 9 случаях из 10 связь один к одному означает, что сущности следует объединить в одну таблицу...

Comment: Если к примеру мне нужно каждому товару назначать штрих-код и печатать его. То для каждого товара должна быть запись в БД? Или в штрих коде не нужен какой то специальный номер товара. Важно знать количество. И когда сканируешь штрих-код для списания, просто уменьшается количество?

Comment: гм... я уже запутался... условия и хотелки слишком часто меняются...

Comment: У меня есть IDEF1X диаграмма того что я делаю

Comment: я так понимаю, она всё же в процессе создания....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И если появится еще один вид продукта, для которого нужно еще одну таблицу и соответственно поле в таблице Расходы.

Именно поэтому данная структура не верна.

В вопросе уже написано, что и `фрукты`, и `овощи` являются `продуктами`, так тогда надо их и сделать `продуктами`, а `расходы` будут вполне естественно выглядеть с одним внешним ключом:

```
Продукт (id, тип_продукта, название, цена, ...)
Расходы (id, id_продукта, количество, дата, ...)
```

Как организовать поле `тип_продукта` зависит от потребностей и расширений БД:

- В самом простом и топорном варианте — это строка. Грубо, сердито, просто.
- Если БД поддерживает перечисляемый тип, то можно создать `ENUM(овощи, фрукты)`. Быстро, компактно, удобно, но добавление нового `типа_продукта` потребует изменение типа.
- Создать дополнительную таблицу `тип_продукта (id, название_типа)` и сделать это поле внешним ключом ссылающимся на неё. Быстро, компактно, легко расширяется, но запросы усложнятся.

Проблемы с этой схемой возникают тогда, когда в таблицах существует значительное количество уникальных полей для каждого типа `продуктов`. Например если добавить в таблицу `пельмени`, для которых нужно указывать `состав`, или `телевизоры`, для которых нужно указывать десятки характеристик. Из этого есть несколько выходов:

- Во-первых можно добавить все возможные поля в таблицу, а `фруктам` указать для тех полей которые для них не имеют смысла значение `NULL`. Этот способ достаточно просто и с ним не возникает проблем, если количество уникальных полей не велико.
- Во-вторых можно сделать структуру с искусственным наследованием:

  ```
  Телевизоры (product_id, диагональ_экрана, гарантия, ...)
  ```

  т.е. общие данные хранятся в `продукты`, а специфические в `телевизоры`. Из плюсов, есть общий код для продуктов, из минусов — много скользких моментов связанных с каскадным удалением и добавлением записей. Работать с такой структурой куда менее приятно чем с предыдущей.
- Третий вариант — наследование таблиц, фактически это тоже что и предыдущее, но большая часть геморроя связанная с добавлением/удалением спрятана под капот движка БД, однако для этого нужна объектно-реляционные СУБД, на сегодняшний день из распространённых вариантов — это Oracle и Postgresql-9.5+ (свободная), а также некоторые другие.

#### Update 1

> Меня смущает то, что каждый раз при создании записи о продукте, нужно вводить его наименование, а не выбирать из списка уже существующих. Например, была бы таблица Фрукты (id, name), пользователь бы выбирал из нее вид фрукта и добавлял продукт.

Можно выбирать из существующих точно также. Список для выбора можно получить с помощью запроса

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM Продукты 
WHERE product_type_id=(SELECT id FROM Типы WHERE name='Фрукты');
```

Если нужно хранить какой-то отдельный список шаблонов, а не просто ранее добавленные, то можно создать для этого отдельную таблицу `product_templates`, где будут настройки по-умолчанию для разных типов продуктов.

```
шаблоны_продуктов (id, type_id, name, ...)
```

Третий вариант, в таблице `Типы` создать древовидную структуру:

```
Типы (id, parent_id, name)
```

Пример данных для конкретики:

```
21, NULL, Фрукты
23, 21,   Яблоки
24, 23,   Семеринко
```

Правда писать рекурсивные запросы — далеко не самое приятное занятие...

Comment: Например если добавить в таблицу телевизоры, для которых кроме прочего надо указывать диагональ_экрана. - Именно это меня и смущает.

Comment: @LFDS расписал подробнее

Answer (score 1):

Правильно Вам не нравится. Потому, что таблиц должно быть не три, а две

- Товары (id, name, type)
- Расходы (id, товар_id, count)

В поле `type` писать, что это за тип - фрукт или овощ.

Еще вариант добавить таблицу types (id, name) а поле `type` сделать внешним ключем

Comment: Но у фруктов и овощей разные свойства. И к примеру, если у меня есть, фрукты одного сорта называемые "Фрукты сорта 1"  и срок годности у них другой. То есть их нельзя записать в таблицу товары под одной записью. А у овощей нет никаких сортов (для примера).

Comment: Не обязательно заполнять все поля таблицы пусть будут все свойства в одной.  А с фруктами и сроками годности пример не понятный

Comment: Но оставлять пустые поля мне кажется не очень правильно.

Comment: @LFDS, это гораздо правильнее, чем создавать две совершенно независимые таблицы...

Comment: @LFDS Вам кажется неправильно. А вообще приведите структуры обеих таблиц, а мы подумаем как их слить в одну

Comment: @LFDS можно еще наследование таблиц сделать